# Resolve two sbt imports with the same classes

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a situation where I have 2 dependencies for a library that have identical classes in each of them.  I need both libraries imported into my code.  Below is a snippet of the libraryDependencies from my build.sbt:

```
"com.company.avro" %% "commons-avro" % "1.1.34",
"com.company.avro" %% "commons-avro-enum" % "1.1.34",
```

What I want to do is something analogous to [shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), however, I am trying to build a library myself so I do not want to build an uber jar at this point.  Instead I'd just like to alias but I cannot figure out how to do this as both jars contain classes with the exact same resolution.

Does anyone know how to get around this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick and easy solution here.

I would suggest that you contact the library author and create a PR which moves all the common code to "commons-avro-core".

Now both "commons-avro" and "commons-avro-enum" would pull in "commons-avro-core" as a transitive dependency.

If this is too much of work for you then move to a different Avro library. Avro4s works very well for me.

Comment: This would be the most straightforward solution, but unfortunately we cannot do this.

Comment: I also end up in situations like the one you mention. let's see if someone offers a better solution.... BTW, is your code not working because of the classes which are shared between the jars? or you just want to eliminate duplication. in your original post, you don't mention exactly what exception or problem you faced.